# Seeing 'SignupForm' object has no attribute 'instance' on Django Form

Tags: django, django-forms

I am on Django 4.0.x and running over and over into the same issue when validating a form.

Always seeing: *'SignupForm' object has no attribute 'instance'*

Here is my view:

```
def signup(request):

if request.method == "POST":
    signup_form = SignupForm(request.POST)
    if signup_form.is_valid():
        email = signup_form.cleaned_data['email']

else:
    signup_form = SignupForm()

return render(request, 'signup.html', {'signup_form': signup_form})
```

and the according forms.py:

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):
email = forms.EmailField(label=_("E-Mail Address"), validators=[EmailValidator()])
password = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"), widget=forms.PasswordInput())
password_confirm = forms.CharField(label=_("Confirm Password"), widget=forms.PasswordInput())

def clean_email(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['email']
    if forms.ValidationError:
        self.add_error('email', forms.ValidationError)
    return data

def clean_password(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['password']
    try:
        validate_password(data, self.instance)
    except forms.ValidationError as error:
        self.add_error('password', error)
    return data
```

cleaned_data also delivers nothing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what your `validate_password` method does, however your problem seems to be coming from the `self.instance` you're passing as one of its parameters. Using `self` instead of `self.instance` would probably solve your problem.